# How to apply Software Restriction policy for specific user in local group policy object?

Tags: c++, windows, active-directory, gpo

I am working on implementing user based software restriction policy programmatically for local group policy object.
If I create a policy through Domain Controller,I do have option for software restriction policy in user configuration but in local group policy editor I don't have option for that.
When I look for the changes made by policy applied from Domain Controller in registry, they modify registry values for specific users on path HKEY_USERS(SID of User)\Softwares\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer\Codeidentifiers
They also have registry.pol stored in SYSvol folder in Domain Controller. When I make the same changes in registry to block any other application, application is getting blocked.
I achieved what I wanted but is it right to modify registry values ?

PS:- I am using Igrouppolicyobject API

Comment: If you mean you are writing directly to the parts of the registry that implement group policy settings, I wouldn't recommend it.  As well as compatibility issues if the implementation ever changes, if Windows notices that there are group policy settings in place that aren't in the actual group policy, it might remove them.

Comment: Thanks Harry, yeah I am making the changes in registry but I am not facing any issues till now, I blocked two applications through two different GPOs by Doamin controller and one application by modifying the registry values,all the three applications have data at same place in registry and all three applications are blocked and settings are not getting deleted even after updating the GPO or restarting the machine. 
So I am not getting how windows will notice that there is group policy settings which are not in policy.

Comment: Some parts of group policy (the exact rules have never been clear) will remove themselves automatically when the relevant policy no longer applies.  That means that when a group policy change is processed, or if the group policy engine decides to do a cleanup for any reason, the artificially introduced settings might be mistaken for settings caused by a no-longer-applicable policy, and automatically removed.  From your testing, I would guess that these settings aren't affected, but that might conceivably change in a future update.  PS: another test you should do is run a `gpupdate /force`.

Comment: I have tried gpupdate /force, registry entry is still there and application is also blocked. Registry cleanup by deleting all group policies related  registry values will delete my entries too and my application will no longer be blocked. But that i will manage by checking the registry values in some interval and reapplying the policies if not present. Is there any other way of group policy clean up ?

Comment: You'd have to ask Microsoft.  And to be honest I wouldn't even trust them to know every possible way in which this might occur; Windows is big, and no single developer understands all of it.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I have another question related to Software Restriction policy,through SRP why can't we block System level application ? Is there any way through which we can block System level application ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "system level application" ?

Comment: Sytem level applications which are not user specific. Like user applications provide services to user, the system level application provide services to Computer.Windows default applications run as System level. I have some 3rd party application which are running as System level, i want to block them through Software Restrictiopn Policy.

Comment: It sounds as if you're talking about system services?  It says [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994620.aspx) that SRP rules enforcement happens in user mode, so it isn't surprising if it doesn't affect code running in local system context and/or code running in session 0.  You could try AppLocker I suppose, though I suspect that it also doesn't affect system services, as a protection against inadvertently making the system unbootable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer,

IGroupPolicyObject - Windows API to create/update policies programmatically.

I would recommend you to go through this links, they will explain in deep about accessing Group Policies programmatically.

[Working with Group Policy Objects Programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsadsi/archive/2009/07/23/working-with-group-policy-objects-programmatically-simple-c-example-illustrating-how-to-modify-a-registry-based-policy.aspx)

[Programmatically updating local policy in Windows](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/03/25/programmatically-updating-local-policy-in-windows/)